# AngularJS - using ng-show within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I'm having an issue using the **ng-show** directive within an **ng-repeat** block.

**The boolean value does not seem to be getting passed to ng-show correctly...**

To show what I mean, here is a screenshot of an example I made in JSFiddle:

[image]

Here is some example markup:

```
<table ng-controller="ActressController" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="actress in actressList">
        <td>
            <span class="actress-name">{{ actress.name }}</span>
            <h4 ng-show="{ actress.name == 'Scarlett' }">Was in Avengers! <span class="note">(should only appear if Scarlett)</span></h4>
            <h2>{{ actress.name == 'Scarlett'}} <span class="note"><-- this statement is correct</span></h2>

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is an example controller:

```
function ActressController($scope) {
    $scope.actressList = [
        {
            name: "Angelina"
        }, {
            name: "Scarlett"
        }, {
            name: 'Mila'
        }, {
            name: 'Megan'
        }
    ]        

}
```

**Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your `ng-show` you don't need { } try this:

```
<h4 ng-show="actress.name == 'Scarlett'">Was in Avengers! <span class="note">
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b004t06z/) for a working sample of an `ng-show` within an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Ahhh simple fix - from looking at the documentation it looked like the curly braces were required.  Thanks!

Comment: @foozhan created a new fiddle showing ng-show within an ng-repeat. thanks for letting me know it was broken!

Comment: Your fiddle is incorrect, as it loops the <ul>s not <il>s. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/6631r5y3/).